# ThreeJS: is it possible to simplify an object / reduce the number of vertexes?

Tags: three.js, autocad, vertex, 3d-modelling

I'm starting to learn ThreeJS. I have some very complex models to display.

These models come from Autocad files that my customer provides.

But sometimes the amount of details in the model is just way too much for the purpose of the website.

I would like to reduce the amount of vertexes in the model to simplify the display and enhance performance.

Is this possible from within ThreeJS?  Or is there maybe an other solution for this?

Comment: three.js r.57 does not include tools for mesh simplification.

Answer (score 11):

There's a modifier called SimplifyModifier that works very well. You'll find it in the Three.js examples

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_modifier_simplifier

Comment: This modifier just puts holes in my models...Does it require them to be indexed? I have tried importing an STL and OBJ format into three.js, but there are no indices. When I simplify my models, it just puts holes in them. The triangle count is down, but only because half of the model was removed, not because it simplified it...

Answer (score 3):

If you can import the model into Blender, you could try *Decimate Modifier*.  In the latest version of Blender, it features three different methods with configurable "amount" parameters.  Depending on your mesh topology, it might reduce the poly count drastically with virtually no visual changes, or it might completely break the model with even a slight reduction attempt. Other 3d packages should include a similar functionality, but I've never used those.

[image: Decimate Modifier in Blender].

Another thing that came into mind: Sometimes when I've encountered a too high-poly Blender model, a good start has been checking if it has a *Subdivision Modifier* applied and removing that if so. While I do not know if there's something similar in Autocad, it might be worth investigating.

Comment: Any change that this code could be ported to typescript or ran as wasm? The Blender decimation is so fast and looks so nice, but the three.js version is slow and broken in 2024...

Answer (score 0):

I updated SimplifyModifier function. it works with Textured models. Here is example:

https://rigmodels.com/3d_LOD.php?view=5OOOEWDBCBR630L4R438TGJCD

you can extract [JS codes](https://rigmodels.com/css/SimplifyModifier.js) and use in your project.